# How to convert word to html in wdRevisionsViewFinal by Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I can convert word to html by Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. However, because of the review annotations in the document, there is a lot of markup information in the converted HTML. How do I convert HTML in no review mode?

This is my convert code, how to fix it?

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

Type wordType = word.GetType();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Documents docs =word.Documents;

Type docsType = docs.GetType();
//aPath is the document file path
object fileName = aPath;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentdocsType.InvokeMember("Open",
System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null,docs, new Object[] { fileName, true, true });

Type docType = doc.GetType();

string ConfigPath = string.Format("{0}.html",aPath);

object saveFileName = ConfigPath;

docType.InvokeMember("SaveAs",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
null, doc, new object[] { saveFileName,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormatwdFormatHTML });

docType.InvokeMember("Close",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
null, doc, new object[] { null, null, null });

wordType.InvokeMember("Quit",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null,word, null);
```

This is the document in review mode screenshot.
[image: eqQ4Ds.md.jpg]

And this is my convert html screenshot.

[image: eqlMPf.md.jpg]

here is he document without review mode screenshot.(no underlines,border,etc)
[image: eqQBDA.jpg]

Thank you so much to everyone who helped.

Comment: See [Removing Comments and Tracked Changes from a Word Document](https://bbhelp.uark.edu/removing-comments-and-tracked-changes-from-a-word-document/). Record macro while doing this, that will tell you how to do it in VBA / .NET.

Comment: not in the word application, I want to use the code to do this job.(a lot of  word files with comments need to convert to html)

Comment: I know, this is why I suggested recording a macro to find out what Word object you need to use to do it programmatically.

Comment: This is a new idea, thanks. I'll try. But I also want to see if it can be solved by Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll's own method.

Comment: The macro recorder gives you insight as to the properties and methods needed to perform actions. The code it generates **is** "the interop".

Comment: @CindyMeister I see, your explanation is very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `.DeleteAllComments()` before saving:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Documents docs = word.Documents;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = docs.Open("c:/temp/test.docx");

object saveFileName = "c:/temp/test.html";

doc.DeleteAllComments();

doc.SaveAs2(saveFileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatHTML);
doc.Close();
```

Comment: thank you very much, I use DeleteAllComments and AcceptAllRevisions to solved this problem,but still a new question. those word file need a password to unlock track revisions, I know the password,but I dont know how to use the password in code.

Comment: 1# answer is here: `doc.Unprotect("your password");`,Maybe it can help other people.